# Cos'è un "alleccamusso"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Cichitto bussava a Prince Street dopo il tramonto. Si stropicciava gli occhi cisposi, incollati dal cimurro, e correva a riempire per Lena il secchio di carbone, lo trascinava su per le scale, per quell’attitudine appunto da larva degli stagni che aspetta pazientemente di volare via e intanto sopporta la palude. Vita invece protestava, reclamava, e aveva spesso assaporato gli **alleccamussi** di Agnello, che le lasciavano sulla guancia l’impronta delle cinque dita.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato della parola "alleccamusso" che appare in questo passaggio? Non l'ho trovata su nessun dizionario. Dal contesto, sembrerebbe uno schiaffo sulla guancia o qualcosa di simile, però mi piacerebbe avere conferma. Immagino si tratti di un termine di origine regionale, possibilmente derivato dal napoletano.

Comment: credo tu abbia perfettamente ragione - penso sia una voce dialettale per indicare un ceffone, dal resto della frase.

Answer (score 1):

Esistono tutta una serie di termini dialettali che paiono una variante di ***alleccamusso*** che, dal contesto da te citato, sembra indicare uno schiaffo o una sberla.

Il [leccamusso](https://it-it.facebook.com/notes/je-so-de-labrizz-e-ne-vaj-fir/lo-schiaffo-in-abruzzo-cambia-nome-a-seconda-dei-casileggere-sotto/396249941655/) in dialetto abruzzese indica uno schiaffo di rovescio ben assestato;

In dialetto napoletano il [liccamusso](https://pulcinella291.forumfree.it/?t=67592895) indica:

> **Liccamusso** lett. Lecca muso. E' uno schaffo a mano aperta che colpisce
>   le labbra del malcapitato

In dialetto cornetano (zona di Viterbo) il [leccamuffo](https://www.artestoriatarquinia.it/wp-content/uploads/bollettini/1983_Bollettino/B.B.%20_IL%20DIALETTO%20CORNETANO.pdf) è qualcosa di più pesante:

> **leccamùffo** (s) – Pugno in faccia che produce lividura. Deriva dal
>   verbo leccare che può significare toccare leggermente; difatti il
>   leccamuffo è veloce e la mano ritorna subito indietro, lasciando la
>   muffa, ovvero quel colore verdastro proprio della percossa ricevuta.
>   Probabile alterazione di laccamuffa che è un colore azzurrognolo che
>   si estrae da alcune specie di lichene.

In questo documento intitolato 
*[Chi è stregato dallo Strega? Rilievi di stile sugli ultimi romanzi vincitori (2002-2009)](https://it-it.facebook.com/notes/je-so-de-labrizz-e-ne-vaj-fir/lo-schiaffo-in-abruzzo-cambia-nome-a-seconda-dei-casileggere-sotto/396249941655/)* ho trovato:

> 101); zezzilli capezzoli” (p. 107); lorcia “sudiciume” (p. 109);
>   scamuso “molto magro” (p. 113); **alleccamussi “ceffoni”** (p. 113, 176);
>   cozzeca “crosta di una ferita”

Il termine ***alleccamussi*** sembra quindi indicare i ceffoni.